# "Or" statement not working in Rails Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following model structure:

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
     belongs_to :location
     has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class Location < ApplicationRecord
     has_and_belongs_to_many :users
     has_many :jobs
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :locations
end
```

This allows me to create jobs for a given location, and then associate/assign users to that job. My user table has an `active` attribute and I am getting an error when I try to query users that are either already assigned to the job or have a status of active. Here is my query:

```
@users = @job.location.users.where(users: { id: @job.user_ids }).or(@job.location.users.where(active: true))
```

The error:

```
ArgumentError (Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:references]):
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
@users = @job.location.users.where(id: @job.user_ids).or(@job.location.users.where(active: true))
```

Comment: I get the following error with this code: `You have passed Hash object to #or. Pass an ActiveRecord::Relation object instead`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. It makes no sense to me why the original query with `.where(users: {id: @job.user_ids})` didn't work though.

Comment: No worries. Just FYI you don't include the objects your searching through in the argument itself, but instead call where on them. So users.where(id: user_ids) rather than where(users: { id: user_ids} )